# Pocket MapleStory Keeps Crashing

Tags: ios, ipod-touch

I have an iPod 4th gen, and I can run Pocket Maplestory on it, and it works, until I select a character, at which point it proceeds to load, then crashes. Here is the crash code: http://pastebin.com/F77Q0DM6

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic before asking a question, it will save you from potential unknowingly posting an off-topic question in the future. My only advice is to E-mail the developer of this game, they will have the means of correcting this issue.

Comment: @KarmaHunter Right, I guess I can do that. And sorry for posting an off-topic question, I'll try to avoid doing so in the future!